# How to lock access to the clipboard programmatically?

Tags: clipboarddata, clipboard-interaction

I wrote some VBA code within MS Excel to automate some tasks. And some of the code use the copy an paste methods. Then I noticed that when the codes using copy and paste are running, they interfere with copy and paste commands from other programs. So my idea is to lock the clipboard so no other programs/process access it during the execution of the Excel codes.

I have not tried any solutions yet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.